# The [habtm] and [has_and_belongs_to_many] tags should be synonymous

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, synonym-request

The tag [habtm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/habtm) is really just a shorter way to write [has-and-belongs-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/has-and-belongs-to-many). Since both tags deal specifically with the Rails association, `has_and_belongs_to_many`, I think they should be made synonyms. (I don't have enough reputation to vote for this myself.)

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised [has-and-belongs-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/has-and-belongs-to-many) even fits the character limit — with a handful to spare. It's a good thing, because then this request can be fulfilled without any awkwardness.

Done.